# Updating rhandsontable from sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable, selectinput

I am challenged with the various operations associated with rhandsontables, though they seem invaluable to the app I am trying to create. My first challenge is that I am trying to update the rhandsontable by filtering the original dataframe from user input, as selected from a dropdown (selectInput).

Here is a simplified reproducible example, that gets me the results I want, but not through the means I wish:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)

counties = as.factor(c(rep("County1", 2), rep("County2", 2)))
compnames = as.factor(c("comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4"))
properties = 1:4
soilsData <- data.frame(county = counties, compname = compnames, property = properties)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectInput(inputId = "selectCounty", label = h4("Select County"), 
                choices = counties,
                selected = "County1",
                multiple = FALSE),
    br(),
    br(),
    rHandsontableOutput('rTable'),
    
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 
    df1 <- df %>% 
        filter(county == "County1", compname == "comp1")
    
    datavalues <- reactiveValues(data = df1)

    output$rTable <- renderRHandsontable ({
        rhandsontable(datavalues$data,
                      rowHeaders = NULL)
    })
}
```

How do I create that df1 through the selected sliderInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `levels` of `counties` for your `choices` in the `ui`.

In addition, in `server`, you can use a `reactive` expression to filter your data. If you wish to react to changes in your `selectInput` (I assume you meant, instead of `sliderInput`) it should be in a reactive expression.

When referencing, you will need to include parentheses. For example, if you call your reactive expression `datavalues`, then `datavalues()` should be used for data in `rhandsontable`.

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "selectCounty", 
              label = h4("Select County"), 
              choices = levels(counties),
              selected = "County1",
              multiple = FALSE),
  br(),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('rTable'),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  datavalues <- reactive({
    soilsData %>% 
      filter(county == input$selectCounty, 
             compname == "comp1")
  })
  
  output$rTable <- renderRHandsontable ({
    rhandsontable(datavalues(),
                  rowHeaders = NULL)
  })
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great! I had tried putting the filter in a reactive function in previous attempts but forgot to put the parentheses after 'datavalues' in rhandsontable! I figured it was something simple I was missing. I really appreciate your help.